# Possible express problem when trying to make post

Tags: node.js, express, pgadmin

I have just found a new Express problem whenever I try to make a post API on Postman. It is the same for all my postings on other API's.

When I make the post there is a "Unhandled rejection error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: cannot set headers after they are sent to the client" error on my IDE console. I have checked all the names of the fields and they match both the tables and pgadmin so that is not the issue.

I think this is something to do with express as postman is throwing an internal server error and I have had similar issues before however I can't see where I have removed anything from after it worked previously.

```
exports.createDiveSpot = async (req, res) => {

    const fileNameWithExtension = `http://localhost:5002/assets/divespot/${req.file.filename}-${req.file.originalname}`
    const newPath = `./assets/diveSpot/${fileNameWithExtension}`

    fs.rename(req.file.path, newPath, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
                res.send(500)
            }
            console.log(req.body)
            diveSpot.create({
                diveLocation: req.body.diveLocation,
                diveRegionID: req.body.diveRegionID,
                diveTypeID: req.body.diveTypeID,
                diveSpotDescription: req.body.diveSpotDescription,
                photos: fileNameWithExtension,
            }).then((data) => {
                res.send(data)
            })
                .catch((err) => {
                    return res.status(500).send({
                        message: err.message || 'Some error occurred while creating the post.',
                    })
                })
        }
    )}
```

server file

```
global.__basedir = __dirname;

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header(
        'Access-Control-Allow-headers',
        'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept',
    );
    next();
});

app.get("/favicon.ico", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "/favicon.ico"));
});

// // parse requests of content-type
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
// bp used to process form data as json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true }));
// multer images is used to pars

// static middleware
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/assets', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'assets')));

//database
const db = require("./server/models");
//    const sequelize = require("pg");
const userLogin = db.userLogin;
const diveLog = db.diveLog;
const diveSpot = db.diveSpot;
const diveSchool = db.diveSchool;
const posts = db.posts;
const photos = db.photos;
const role = db.userRole;
const current = db.currents;
```

error message

```
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\James Greene\WebstormProjects\softwaredevproject\SustainableScuba\
backend\assets\article\ec16dac399bb581c17116148f5395115' -> 'C:\Users\James Greene\WebstormProjects\softwaredevproject\Sustain
ableScuba\backend\assets\article\http:\localhost:5002\assets\article\ec16dac399bb581c17116148f5395115-sharkfeat.jpg'] {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'rename',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\James Greene\\WebstormProjects\\softwaredevproject\\SustainableScuba\\backend\\assets\\article\\ec16dac399
bb581c17116148f5395115',
  dest: 'C:\\Users\\James Greene\\WebstormProjects\\softwaredevproject\\SustainableScuba\\backend\\assets\\article\\http:\\loc
alhost:5002\\assets\\article\\ec16dac399bb581c17116148f5395115-sharkfeat.jpg'
}
express deprecated res.send(status): Use res.sendStatus(status) instead controllers\article.controller.js:15:21
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "articles" ("articleID","articleTitle","articleContent","photos","userID","articleTypeID") VA
LUES (DEFAULT,$1,$2,$3,$4,$5) RETURNING *;
Unhandled rejection Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:485:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (...vproject\SustainableScuba\backend\node_modules\
express\lib\response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (...edevproject\SustainableScuba\backend\node_modules\ex
press\lib\response.js:170:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (...aredevproject\SustainableScuba\backend\node_modules\ex
press\lib\response.js:267:15)
    at ServerResponse.send (...redevproject\SustainableScuba\backend\node_modules\ex
press\lib\response.js:158:21)
    at ...redevproject\SustainableScuba\backend\controllers\article.controller.js:27
:37
    at tryCatcher (...aredevproject\SustainableScuba\backend\node_modules\sequelize\n
ode_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (...._modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:547:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (...bird\js\release\promise.js:604:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (....ird\js\release\promise.js:649:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (...roject\SustainableScuba\backend\node_module
s\sequelize\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:725:18)
    at _drainQueueStep (...\backend\node_modules\sequel
ize\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:93:12)
```

[image]

Comment: `return res.send(500)`

Comment: Yes I have changed the return res data and i'm still getting the same error. Should I be putting my API inside a try catch loop? I know this error is usually to do with two messages being sent but I think there must be underlying issues.

Comment: can you show full error and add the code which calls `createDiveSpot`, other than what suggested there is not any code in shown code that would cause the error, you did restart app after change right?

Comment: That's it updated now. Could it be something to do with the folder I am posting the file into? The images are appearing as if they were binary now instead of image files.

Comment: read the errors, `C:\Users\James Greene\WebstormProjects\softwaredevproject\Sustain
ableScuba\backend\assets\article\http:\localhost:5002\assets\article\ec16dac399bb581c17116148f5395115-sharkfeat.jpg` is not a filepath, also its showing in the same error that your still executing the query, so you must not be doing `return res.send(500)`, though I think from the other error it should be `return res.sendStatus(500)`

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to formulate a method for creating the unique filename, placing it in the correct folder and it being inserted with the full url in Postgres.

The saves the image as the correct file type and produces no error messages on the console.

Previously the "http" address in the fileNameWithExtension was causing problems on all my file forms.

```
exports.createDiveSpot = async (req, res) => {

    const fileNameWithExtension = `${req.file.filename}-${req.file.originalname}`
    const newPath = `./assets/diveSpot/${fileNameWithExtension}`
    const fileNameWithPath = `http://localhost:5002/assets/diveSpot/${fileNameWithExtension}`

    fs.rename(req.file.path, newPath, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
                return res.send(500)
            }
            diveSpot.create({
                diveLocation: req.body.diveLocation,
                diveRegionID: req.body.diveRegionID,
                diveTypeID: req.body.diveTypeID,
                diveSpotDescription: req.body.diveSpotDescription,
                photos: fileNameWithPath,
            }).then((data) => {
                console.log(req.body)
```